# ConversionJob in SharePoint2010 to convert docx to pdf takes long time or very slow

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, pdf-conversion

I have been using **ConversionJob** in **SharePoint 2010** to convert the docx file to pdf and it takes a long time, around 10 mins.

Is that really very slow or is it because of the resources on my server is bit slow? Because it takes 10 minutes in my development server and I am worried about the time taken through internet.

Is there any way to make it quicker or any other solution to use within SharePoint 2010?

I am using C#, Open XML to manipulation and creation of docx first and then SharePoint 2010 ConversionJob to convert to pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConversionJob runs by default every 10 minutes, if I remember correctly. Probably you need to wait until the timer job starts again. From my experience, converting Word document to PDF does not take much time.

Go to your Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Review job definitions -> find Word Automation Services Timer Job and see what schedule is set.

Comment: Is there a way to start this timer job manually, like if we go to scheduling settings there is an option "Run Now" which will start the Job Immediately. Can we do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors that can affect performance.

1. Take a look how your code affects the CPU and RAM in development with a document or set of documents that will mimic production like data.
2. Take a look where you are getting the .docx and putting the .pdf.  This is were network latency can come into play and have nothing to do with your code.
3. You should show some of your code so we can take a look at any optimization available.